# Generic class to store variable content

Tags: c#, generics

I want to create a structure to store data consumed from a Web Service with the followind specs:

Response:

- Field 1 - InstructionType: Can be 1 (PreferredDay), 2 (SVP), 3 (Neighbour)
- Field 2: Some variable data. Its type depends on Field 1. So if:
- Field 1 == 1 then Field 2 type will be of DateTime (dd.MM.yyyy)
- Field 1 == 2 then Field 2 type will be of type string.
- Field 1 == 3 then Field 2 type will be of type string

So, I started up with the following enum:

```
public enum InstructionType
{
    None = 0,
    PreferredDay = 1,
    ServicePoint = 2,
    Neighbour = 3
}
```

And the generic class:

```
public abstract class Instruction<T>
{
    public InstructionType Type { get; private set; }
    public T Data { get; private set; }

    public Instruction(InstructionType type, T data)
    {
        this.Type = type;
        this.Data = data;
    }

}
```

and concrete classes:

```
 public class PreferredDayInstruction : Instruction<DateTime>
{
    public PreferredDayInstruction(DateTime data) 
        : base (InstructionType.PreferredDay, data) {}
}

    public class ServicePointInstruction: Instruction<string>
{
    public ServicePointInstruction(string data) 
        : base (InstructionType.ServicePoint, data) {}
}

    public class NeughbourInstruction: Instruction<string>
{
    public NeughbourInstruction(string data) 
        : base (InstructionType.Neighbour, data) {}
}
```

When parsing web service's response created a public function:

```
     public Instruction DeliveryInstruction() <---Compiler error here "Instruction"
    {
        if (resultFromWebservice.Field1 == 1)
           return new PreferredDayInstruction((DateTime)Field2);
        if (resultFromWebservice.Field1 == 2)
           return new ServicePointInstruction(Field2);  
        if (resultFromWebservice.Field1 == 3)
           return new NeighbourInstruction(Field2);  

    }
```

and here is the problem. Can't return objects of generic type.

Tried with with Interface, factories, and other stuff, but allways with the same problem. So, is there any way to archieve this? maybe it's not possible or maybe is so easy I can't see now. Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**
Compiler error on **BOLD** Instruction
Error   1   Using the generic type 'NAMESPACE.Instruction' requires '1' type arguments

I forgot..I'm using .NET 3.5

Comment: `Can't return objects of generic type` <= what cant return an object that implements a generic? Is this a compile error message? If so please post the entire error message. Is this an Exception? If so include all the Exception details (stack trace, type, message, repeat for inner exceptions);

Comment: Compiler error. Post updated

Comment: If the method is always returning a `PreferredDayInstruction()` object, what's the point of having the declared return value `Instruction` (even assuming that's legal syntax, which it's not)? It's very unclear what it is exactly you're trying to achieve here. There's nothing fundamentally wrong with the generic `Instruction<T>` type, but how you're using it obviously doesn't work and you haven't provided enough context to anyone to help you understand how to use it correctly.

Comment: @PeterDuniho DeliveryInstruction function edited. It shouldn't always return a PreferredDayInstruction, but a object derived from Instruction<T>. Could be PreferredDayInstruction, ServicePointInstruction or NeighbourInstruction. Maybe in the future, could be a ThrowToTheRiverIntruction(int riverId) for instance.

Comment: Please explain what a caller is supposed to do with this scenario. You have a method that can return `Instruction<DateTime>` _and_ `Instruction<string>`. At compile time, the return type needs to be known. What's your plan for the call site? Your question is still lacking a good [mcve] that would illustrate all of this. Possible solutions, among others, include splitting the method into two non-generic methods, or creating a non-generic base class the method can return. But it's still not possible to say what would work in your case.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you may be starting off with an intent to use generics rather than using them because you've identified a need. Often (not always) when that gets difficult it's because it didn't actually fit what you were trying to do.

What seems odd in this case is that you have both a generic type and an `enum` to indicate the type. This is likely to cause you a few problems.

First it looks like you're trying to create a one-size-fits all class to model different types of behaviors. That will start off confusing and get more confusing. Think of most classes that are part of the .NET framework, and imagine what would happen if they had properties like `Field1` and `Field2`, and you couldn't tell from looking at them what they were for. And in one method they're used for one thing, but in a another case they mean something else.

Also, if you're trying to put different types of instructions in one class, that suggests that maybe you're going to try passing them all to one method, and that method figures out what to do, and maybe calls other methods. (I'm guessing that because of the `enum`. Perhaps you're going to handle the input differently depending on which value it contains.) That one method will get really hard to maintain.

I'd recommend waiting on generics until you're sure you need them. And if you have different types of instructions you're likely better off writing a different class for each one with the properties it needs and names that describe them, and writing methods for each of them to do what they need to do. If you need lots of classes, make lots of them.

It's very easy to fall into the trap of trying to solve problems that don't exist, like how do I write one class that covers a bunch of different needs. The answer usually that you don't need to. You'll get better results from writing more classes that each do *fewer* things.

Comment: I identified a need because I saw Instruction Data property is variable, AKA object. So it should be candidate of being generic. But I agree with you "when that gets difficult it's because it didn't actually fit".

Comment: " Think of most classes that are part of the .NET framework, and imagine what would happen if they had properties like Field1 and Field2" Of course, web service's field names, aren't Field 1 and Field 2. In fact, the response is a fixed length string. Yes, XML or JSON. No matter why it's done, that why. It's out of scope of this post

Comment: Agree with the rest of your answer. So, I finally went to another aproach. I'll post right now.

Answer (score 0):

Believe me that I tried to do my best to explain what was my problem and what I needed in order to solve it. In a nutshell, the question was quite simple. Is this possible or not? So, is there a way to return a common type for these 3 classes? Answer is no, as they don't share any root. They all derive from Instruction, but aren't compatible each other. That's what I learned from this experience.

As another example, lets take another .NET framework's generic type.

```
public class ListOfString : List<string> { }

public class ListOfInt : List<int> { }

public class ListOfDecimal : List<decimal> { }
```

And, in another place of the application, get a method who returns one of this List based on some logic:

```
public class Logic
{
    public List<> GetList(Type t) <----This can't be done
    {

        if (t == typeof(string))
            return new ListOfString();
        if (t == typeof(int))
            return new ListOfInt();
        if (t == typeof(decimal))
            return new ListOfDecimal();
        else return null;
    }
```

}

Please, keep in mind that this is just a stupid sample just to show what's the point of this post.

By the way, in the case of List the following can be done, because there is a non generic different version of IList:

```
public IList GetList(Type t) 
{
      ....
}
```

But I can't think of a way to do this in my particular case.

Anyway, I  finally followed another approach. I reallized that what I really wanted is to ensure Data property is valid. If it it's supposed to be a date there, ensure date is valid. Is it a string, ensure it has the right length or whatever rule it must follow.

So this is the final solution:

The enum:

```
public enum InstructionType
{
    None = 0,
    PreferredDay = 1,
    ServicePoint = 2,
    Neighbour = 3
}
```

The base class:

```
 public abstract class Instruction
{
    public InstructionType Type { get; private set; }
    public string Data { get; private set; } <---Type String

    public Instruction(InstructionType type, string data)
    {
        this.Type = type;
        this.Data = IsValid(data) ? data : string.Empty;
    }

    public abstract bool IsValid(string data); <--the rule.
}
```

The concrete classes:

```
public class PreferredDayInstruction : Instruction
{
    public PreferredDayInstruction(string date)
        : base(InstructionType.PreferredDay, date) { }

    public override bool IsValid(string data)
    {
        string[] formats = {"dd.MM.yyyy", "d.MM.yyyy",
                            "dd.MM.yy", "d.MM.yy"};
        try
        {
            data = data.Replace('/', '.').Replace('-', '.');
            var dateparts = data.Split('.');
            DateTime date = new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(dateparts[2]),
                                         Convert.ToInt32(dateparts[1]),
                                         Convert.ToInt32(dateparts[0]));

            //DateTime.ParseExact(data, formats, null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal);
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}


    public class ServicePointInstruction : Instruction
{
    public ServicePointInstruction(string data)
        : base (InstructionType.ServicePoint, data) { }

    public override bool IsValid(string data)
    {
        return ServicePointBarcodeValidator.Validate(data); 
    }
}

    public class NeighbourInstruction : Instruction
{
    public NeighbourInstruction(string data) :
        base(InstructionType.Neighbour, data) { }

    public override bool IsValid(string data)
    {
        return data.Length <= 70;
    }
}
```

A factory class, who's responsability is to create and return the correct object based on the enum:

```
    public static class DeliveryInstructionFactory
{

    public static Instruction Create(int type, string data)
    {
        return Create((InstructionType)type, data);
    }

    public static Instruction Create(InstructionType type, string data)
    {
        switch (type)
        {
            case InstructionType.PreferredDay:
                return new PreferredDayInstruction(data);
            case InstructionType.ServicePoint:
                return new ServicePointInstruction(data);
            case InstructionType.Neighbour:
                return new NeighbourInstruction(data);
            default:
                return null;
        }

    }
}
```

And finally, as now all of they share the same root, object can be created on webservice's response parser:

```
    public Instruction DeliveryInstruction()
    {
        try
        {
            int instructionCode = int.Parse(observation.Substring(173,2));
            string instructionData = observation.Substring(175, 10);

            return DeliveryInstructionFactory.Create(instructionCode, instructionData);            }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Error("[ValidationBarcodeResponse] DeliveryInstructions aren't in the correct format", ex);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Hope this now fits on a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)